# Typescript check if property exist

Tags: typescript

I have a function that can take 2 different types of objects as argument

```
myFunc(arg: (Obj1 | Obj2))
```

In my function I want something like:

```
let val = ( arg instance of Obj1 ) ? Obj1.propOnlyOnObj1 : Obj2.propOnlyOnObj2;
```

since these properties only exist on one of the ojbect typescript throws errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work fine

```
class A {
    public field1: string = 'asd';
}

class B {
    public field2: string = 'def';
}

function test(arg: A | B) {
    var value = arg instanceof A ? arg.field1 : arg.field2;
    //use value
}
```

You can play with it here: [Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=class%20A%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20field1%3A%20string%20%3D%20'asd'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20B%20%7B%0D%0A%09public%20field2%3A%20string%20%3D%20'def'%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20test(arg%3A%20A%20%7C%20B)%20%7B%0D%0A%09var%20value%20%3D%20arg%20instanceof%20A%20%3F%20arg.field1%20%3A%20arg.field2%3B%0D%0A%09%0D%0A%09%2F%2Fuse%20value%0D%0A%7D)

Comment: My console says:

    Argument of type 'typeof A' is not assignable to parameter of type 'A | B'.
    Type 'typeof A' is not assignable to type 'B'.
    Property 'field2' is missing in type 'typeof A'.

Comment: Sorry I think my problem is that I'm passing an object that isn't an instance of classA but of interfaceA. Could that be it?

Comment: Could be. Try sharing a minimal, complete, verifiable example. Classes, interfaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

With [lodash.has](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#has)

```
let val = _.has(Obj1, 'propOnlyOnObj1') ? 
    Obj1.propOnlyOnObj1 : Obj2.propOnlyOnObj2;
```

Comment: It's an overkill for something as simple as `'propOnlyOnObj1' in Obj1` in vanilla js.